# Pandas Data Frame find index according to column value

Tags: python, performance, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a data frame lets say "df".
Now one of the columns of the data frame is named "itemID". I would like to get some how very fast the row index according to a value on the column "itemID".

When I do:

```
df[df['itemID']==X]
```

The performance is quite slow.

Is there a way to create something like a hash-index in order to do the above?

Comment: Do you think `df[df['itemID']==X]` ?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `df[df['itemID'] == x]` can you explain how large and complex your df is, the `dtypes` involved, any missing values, and how fast are you requiring here?

Comment: My df contains 3.2M rows. The itemID is an integer. The df also contains some other columns.

Comment: Are the ids unique? You could set it as the index if so

Comment: Yes the ids are unique.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html).

[Docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-overview.html#scope) say:

**The following class of computations works well:**

> Trivially parallelizable operations (fast):
>
> Row-wise selections: df[df.x > 0]

You can also check how [Create Dask DataFrames](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html).

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                   'itemID': [1,2,4,4]})

print (df)
    A  itemID
0  A0       1
1  A1       2
2  A2       4
3  A3       4

#Construct a dask objects from a pandas objects
df_dask = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

#Row-wise selections
print (df_dask[df_dask.itemID == 4].compute())
    A  itemID
2  A2       4
3  A3       4
```

Comment: cool. didn't know dask but it will help some of my codes for sure.